# OS memory managment

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

I'm studying about operating systems currently and I am a bit confused.

When a process is started for the first time, does the OS know the size of the heap? (I am guessing it knows the size of the data & code segments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heap is just a concept. There is no real, single heap. A heap is a block of memory that can be used for dynamic memory requests. A heap is created by library routines that allocate dynamic memory. There can be many heaps or no heap at all.

The OS never knows the size of the process heap.

Comment: Thanks, that sums it up.